# Adding elements to ObservableCollection doesn't update UI

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I want a `TabControl` with dynamic `TabItems`. I have an `ObservableCollection` property in my code-behind file and when I add elements to this property I expect the GUI to add a new `TabItem` element.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Window, Path=PositionTabs, Mode=OneWay}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header, Mode=OneTime}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Content, Mode=OneTime}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<PositionTab> PositionTabs { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PositionTabs = new ObservableCollection<PositionTab>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            PositionTabs.Add(new PositionTab(i));
        }
    }
}
```

**PositionTab.cs**

```
public class PositionTab
{
    public int PosIndex { get; }
    public string Header => $"Position {PosIndex + 1}";  
    public string Content => "Content";

    public PositionTab(int posIndex)
    {
        PosIndex = posIndex;
    }
}
```

When I start my application I only have a empty `TabControl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just move the set up of your data:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        PositionTabs = new ObservableCollection<PositionTab>();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            PositionTabs.Add(new PositionTab(i));
        }

        InitializeComponent();


    }
```

The problem you're seeing is that the observablecollection is null initially.
This is something most mvvm developers will never see happen so it looks weird to us.
I'd normally have a viewmodel, that would implement inotifypropertychanged and when I set up such a collection it would raise property changed on the collection and it'd all just work.
To do this all in code behind is not usual practice... but... to show that working:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window,  INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<PositionTab> PositionTabs { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PositionTabs = new ObservableCollection<PositionTab>();
        RaisePropertyChanged("PositionTabs");
        for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
        {
            PositionTabs.Add(new PositionTab(i));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I planned to refactor my application later and use/learn MVVM but I'm currently a bit under time pressure so I just want it to work ^^.

Comment: Yep. You definitely want to adopt mvvm if you do wpf development commercially though. It's not just a nice to have fancy thing. Not just for unit testing.